# android error displaying parseobject through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parse-platform

I want to be able to get a parseobject string form a list of users and display hem on another activity, but when i send them to another activity through the intent the string is not displayed, but the image uri is displayed and an image is shown on the activity, but not the string.

ActivityOne

```
    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    query.addDescendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (e == null) {
                // We found messages!
                mMessages = messages;

                String[] usernames = new String[mMessages.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for(ParseObject message : mMessages) {
                    usernames[i] = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                    i++;
                }
                if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                    MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(
                            getListView().getContext(),
                            mMessages);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else {
                    // refill the adapter!
                    ((MessageAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).refill(mMessages);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ParseObject message = mMessages.get(position);
    ParseFile file = message.getParseFile(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE);
    String messagetxt= message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_MESSGAE);
    String information = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_INFORMATION);

    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());

    // view the image
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
    intent.setData(fileUri);
    intent.putExtra(messagetxt, "message");
    intent.putExtra(information, "information");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

AcivityTwo

```
    Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
    Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri.toString()).into(image);
    String messagestring = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    String infostring = getIntent().getStringExtra("information");

    message.setText(messagestring);
    info.setText(infostring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mistoken this:

```
intent.putExtra(messagetxt, "message");
intent.putExtra(information, "information");
```

I think should be:

```
intent.putExtra("message",messagetxt);
intent.putExtra("information", information);
```

The first parameter is key and second is value for the key.